# MudBlazor: How to set focus to an element added dynamically via the bound model?

Tags: mudblazor

We're experimenting with MudBlazor for some of our new UIs, and have one that uses a `MudTreeView` for editing tree-shaped info. Here's a simplified and contrived example of the kind of thing we have:

```
<MudTreeView Items="@_fields" Hover="true" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate Context="item">
        <MudTreeViewItem Items="@item.Children">
            <BodyContent>
                <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr auto; align-items: center; width: 100%">
                    <MudTextField @ref="_focus[item.Id]" T="string" @bind-Value="@item.Name"/>
                </div>
            </BodyContent>
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudTreeView>

<MudButton OnClick="() => AddTo()">Add</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="() => FocusThree()">Focus three</MudButton>

@code {
    public class Node {
        public Node(string name) {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Name = name;
        }
        public string Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public HashSet<Node> Children {get;set;}
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    HashSet<Node> _fields;
    Dictionary<string, MudTextField<string>> _focus = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(0);
        _fields = new HashSet<Node> {
            new Node("one"),
            new Node("two")
        };
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        if (!firstRender) return;
        await Focus("two");
    }

    public async Task Focus(string name) {
        var field = _fields.Single(x => x.Name == name);
        var focus = _focus[field.Id];
        await focus.InputReference.ElementReference.FocusAsync(false);
    }

    public async Task AddTo() {
        _fields.Add(new Node("three"));
        // how to set focus to the new MudTextField generated when an item is added to the bound model?
        await Focus("three"); // doesn't work because there's no element reference yet
    }

    public async Task FocusThree() {
        await Focus("three"); // works fine
    }
}
```

With this we're able to edit nodes in place, and adding/removing nodes from the bound model causes them to be added or removed from the view, and we're happy.

Now we're trying to have newly-added fields in the tree get focus (and scroll into view) when the user clicks the button to add them to the model. It's obvious why we can't set focus immediately after adding to the model (there's no rendered component to focus on), and we know that `FocusAsync` works successfully if invoked at some point in human-time after the component *does* get rendered.

We did attempt to implement an `ObservableDictionary` for the tracking of `MudTextField`s, whereby, as they get added to the view, they show up in the dictionary, which raises an event, the handler for which then attempts to `FocusAsync`, but it turns out that even here there's no `InputReference` yet (it's `null`).

Is there a clean way to be notified when the newly-generated `MudTextField` (and its `input` element) is ready to accept a `FocusAsync` attempt? If there's no MudBlazor-native way to do it, what's the cleanest javascript-y way?

**UPDATE**: We were able to get something working using the ObservableDictionary, where the event handler starts a timer that checks the `InputReference` each tick, and set focus when it's no longer null (and of course disposes the timer). Needless to say we don't consider this a particularly clean solution.